# forEach vs for in: Different Behavior When Calling a Method

Tags: dart

I noticed that `forEach` and `for in` to produce different behavior. I have a list of `RegExp` and want to run `hasMatch` on each one. When iterating through the list using `forEach`, `hasMatch` never returns true. However, if I use `for in`, `hasMatch` returns true.

Sample code:

```dart
class Foo {
  final str = "Hello";
  final regexes = [new RegExp(r"(\w+)")];

  String a() {
    regexes.forEach((RegExp reg) {
      if (reg.hasMatch(str)) {
        return 'match';
      }
    });
    return 'no match';
  }

  String b() {
    for (RegExp reg in regexes) {
      if (reg.hasMatch(str)) {
        return 'match';
      }
    }
    return 'no match';
  }
}

void main() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  print(foo.a()); // prints "no match"
  print(foo.b()); // prints "match"
}
```

([DartPad with the above sample code](https://dartpad.dev/daab4a914762256369bbf582ffcfb7cd))

The only difference between the methods `a` and `b` is that `a` uses `forEach` and `b` uses `for in`, yet they produce different results. Why is this?

Comment: Code inside `forEach` is executed asynchronously. Therefore `a` returns with 'no match' before any regex is matched.

Comment: @HlibBabii No, that's wrong. `forEach` is *not* asynchronous and *must* not be used with asynchronous operations.  The problem here is that the `return` statement returns from different functions.

Comment: Another alternative: `regexes.any((reg) => reg.hasMatch(str)) ? "match" : "no match"`

Answer (score 23):

Although there is a [`prefer_foreach` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_foreach.html), that recommendation is specifically for cases where you can use it with a tear-off (a reference to an existing function).  Effective Dart [recommends *against* using `Iterable.forEach` with anything else](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal), and there is a corresponding [`avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls.html) to enforce it.

Except for those simple cases where the callback is a tear-off, `Iterable.forEach` is not any simpler than using a basic and more general `for` loop.  There are more pitfalls using `Iterable.forEach`, and this is one of them.

- `Iterable.forEach` is a function that takes a *callback* as an argument.  `Iterable.forEach` is not a control structure, and the callback is an ordinary function.  You therefore cannot use `break` to stop iterating early or use `continue` to skip to the next iteration.
- A `return` statement in the callback *returns from the callback*, and the return value is ignored.  The caller of `Iterable.forEach` will never receive the returned value and will never have an opportunity to propagate it.  For example, in:

  ```dart
  bool f(List<int> list) {
    for (var i in list) {
      if (i == 42) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  ```

  the `return true` statement returns from the function `f` and stops iteration.  In contrast, with `forEach`:

  ```dart
  bool g(List<int> list) {
    list.forEach((i) {
      if (i == 42) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  ```

  the `return true` statement returns from only the callback.  The function `g` will not return until it completes *all* iterations and reaches the `return false` statement at the end.  This perhaps is clearer as:

  ```dart
  bool callback(int i) {
    if (i == 42) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  bool g(List<int> list) {
    list.forEach(callback);
    return false;
  }
  ```

  which makes it more obvious that:

  1. There is no way for `callback` to cause `g` to return `true`.
  2. `callback` does not return a value along all paths.

  (That's the problem you encountered.)
- [`Iterable.forEach` must not be used with asynchronous callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719805/).  Because any value returned by the callback is ignored, asynchronous callbacks can never be waited upon.

I should also point out that if you enable Dart's new null-safety features, which enable stricter type-checking, your `forEach` code will generate an error because it returns a value in a callback that is expected to have a `void` return value.

A notable case where `Iterable.forEach` can be simpler than a regular `for` loop is if the object you're iterating over might be `null`:

```dart
List<int>? nullableList;
nullableList?.forEach((e) => ...);
```

whereas a regular `for` loop would require an additional `if` check or doing:

```dart
List<int>? nullableList;
for (var e in nullableList ?? []) {
  ...
}
```

(In JavaScript, `for`-`in` has unintuitive pitfalls, so `Array.forEach` often is recommended instead.  Perhaps that's why a lot of people seem to be conditioned to use a `.forEach` method over a built-in language construct.  However, Dart does not share those pitfalls with JavaScript.)

Comment: > "Except for simple, specialized cases where the callback is a tearoff (a reference to an existing function), I don't think that it's any simpler than using a basic and more general for loop."

Those are exactly the cases where the lint recommends using `forEach`. (Also, it is just a lint, it's entirely optional whether you want to use it).

Comment: @lrn Ah, I misunderstood the `prefer_forEach` lint.  I also remembered that there is an `avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls` lint.

Answer (score 0):

[jamesdin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin)! Everything you have shared about the limitations of `forEach` is correct however there's one part where you are wrong. In the code snippet showing the example of how you the return value from `forEach` is ignored, you have `return true;` inside the callback function for `forEach` which is not allowed as the callback has a return type of `void` and returning any other value from the callback is not allowed.

Although you have mentioned that returning a value from within the callback will result in an error, I'm just pointing at the code snippet.

[Here's the signature for forEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekNUl.png)

Also, some more pitfalls of `forEach` are:

- One can't use `break` or `continue` statements.
- One can't get access to the index of the item as opposed to using the regular `for loop`