# dart how to break forEach in if

Tags: for-loop, dart

I want a list.forEach and if in forEach and when this if return true I want to break this code like that

```
  list.forEach((element){
       if(element == "a"){
         break
      }
    })
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65417146/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real answer on a real question about `how to break forEach in if`.

```
void main() {
  final seq1 = [0, 1, 2];
  final result = <int>[];
  try {
    seq1.forEach((e) {
      if (e == 2) throw 'Stop this immediately';
      result.add(e);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // What? Something happened?
  }

  print(result);
}
```

Result:

```
[0, 1]
```

Not the most practical option, but it works.
That is, fully functional, for your case (break forEach).
The answer fully answers your question.
Do you have any other question?

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite your forEach call to a for-each loop:

```
  for (final element in list) {
    if (element == "a") {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The second version does not the same as the first though.

Comment: @nvoigt You are right. I have deleted my second "solution".