# The return type 'bool' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the below error when using the `forEach` loop for the items when used in the function when returning the values.

```
bool validatedValues(List<String> values){
    values.forEach((i){
      if (i.length > 3){
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Im using dart null safety sdk version: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Complete error:

```
The return type 'bool' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure
```

Comment: [Avoid using `Iterable.forEach` for anything but tear-offs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `return true` inside your `forEach`. `forEach` is expecting a `void Function(T)` not a `bool Function(T)`.

I think that what you try to achieve is:

```dart
bool validatedValues(List<String> values){
  bool result = false;
  values.forEach((i){
    if (i.length > 3){
      result = true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Or, probably more elegant:

```dart
bool validatedValues(List<String> values) => values.any((i) => i.length > 3);
```

- `bool any(bool test(E element));`

  This returns `true` if at least one item of the List is validated by `test`. [ref](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/any.html)
- `bool every(bool test(E element));`

  This return `true` if all the items of the List are validated by `func`. [ref](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/every.html)

Comment: Or, in general, prefer ordinary `for` loops over `Iterable.forEach`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, why so?

Comment: Because `Iterable.forEach` has a number of pitfalls while usually offering no advantage.  See my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change foreach by classic for to resolve this

```
bool validatedValues(List<String> values){
    values.forEach((i){
      if (i.length > 3){
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

you can change it by

```
bool validatedValues(List<String> values){
    for (String i in values){
      if (i.length > 3){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```