# Is there a way to access the index/key in a ForEach with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, foreach, key

I'm attempting to run the following foreach loop so I can remove a specific entry.

```
textMap.results.forEach((element) {
   textMap.results.removeAt(**element.KEY**);
   print(element.KEY)
}
```

Is it possible to reference the index/key of a foreach loop??
I've tested this with a basic iterator but if the list contains multiple entries that needs to be deleted then the index becomes out of sync once an initial item gets removed. Hence why I am looking for an index/key

Comment: So you basically want a counter for each element in the loop?

Comment: not quite as I've tested this with a basic iterator but if the list contains multiple entries that will be deleted then the index becomes out of sync once an item gets removed. Hence when I am looking for an index/key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [avoid using `Iterable.forEach` except for trivial cases](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal).  If you want element indices, just use a normal looping construct (e.g. `for`, `while`).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/.

In your example code, you unconditionally remove each item, so you could just call `List.clear()` at the end, which would be much simpler and more efficient.  That should be O(1).

If you don't want to remove *all* items and instead need to *conditionally* remove multiple items, there are a few ways you could do it.

- Use [`List.removeWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) if possible.  I expect this to be O(n) with respect to the length of the list.
- Process the items from last to first so that removing an element from the list does not affect iteration:

  ```dart
  for (var i = textMap.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    print(textMap.results[i]); // Do something with the element.
    if (shouldRemove(textMap.results[i])) {
      textMap.results.removeAt(i);
    }
  }
  ```
- If you must process the elements in order, you can first collect a list of indices to remove and then remove them separately:

  ```dart
  var indicesToRemove = <int>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < textMap.results.length; i += 1) {
    print(textMap.results[i]); // Do something with the element.
    if (shouldRemove(textMap.results[i])) {
      indicesToRemove.add(i);
    }
  }
  // Remove in reverse order so that removing items does not affect
  // unprocessed indices.
  for (var index in indicesToRemove.reversed) {
    textMap.results.removeAt(index);
  }
  ```
- Alternatively use a `while` loop that conditionally increments the list index:

  ```dart
  var i = 0;
  while (i < textMap.results.length) {
    print(textMap.results[i]); // Do something with the element.
    if (shouldRemove(textMap.results[i])) {
      textMap.results.removeAt(i);
      // Iterate again at the same index.
      continue;
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  ```

The last three approaches would be O(m*n) where n is the length of the list and m is the number of items to remove.