# Why is 'using forEach with a function literal' considered a bad practice in Dart?

Tags: dart, lint

I'm getting this lint when using `forEach`:

```
Avoid using `forEach` with a function literal.
```

This a sample code:

```
class AB {
  int data;
  AB(this.data);
  int call() => data;
}

void main() {
  var myList = [AB(1), AB(3)];
  myList.forEach((e) => print(e()));  // <--- lint raised here
}
```

Comment: Because except in trivial cases, [you should prefer using a regular `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/).

Answer (score 0):

The lint is based on the style guide, which [says](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal) that you should use a `for`/`in` loop instead.

```dart
for (var e in myList) {
  print(e());
}
```

That is both more efficient and more readable.