# A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, dart-null-safety

- I encountered this problem while working with Flutter & Firebase (firestore), I did my research and couldn`t find anything helpful.
- I want to turn my streams I get from firestore into a stream of widgets `StreamBuilder()`.
- Here is Firestore object initialization  `final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;`
- Here is the method where I try to get my data from firestore as a stream

  ```
  void messagesStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('message').snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Here is StreamBuilder widget insdie my widget tree =>

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('message').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final messages = snapshot.data!;
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                for (var message in messages) // <== I get My error here
                   *// The type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' used in the 'for' loop must 
                   // implement Iterable.*
                  {
                  final messageText = message.data['text'];
                  final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
                  final messageWidget =
                      Text('$messageText from @$messageSender');
                  messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
              },
            ),
```

- If I removed the null check operator from `final messages = snapshot.data;`
  I get a different error which is

*A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as an iterator.*

Answer (score 1):

One way to easily deal with nullable iterables in a `for` loop is to use `??` to provide a non-nullable fallback value.  For example:

```dart
List<int>? nullableList;
for (var element in nullableList ?? <int>[]) {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use the conditional-member-access operator with `forEach`:

```dart
List<int>? nullableList;
nullableList?.forEach((element) {
  ...
});
```

although [generally I recommend normal `for` loops over `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I just solved it. btw I tried your suggestion before it didnt work I guess the error message was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may check if "snapshot.data" is not null before anything else.

```
// This basically means that if you have data, you show the widget CircularProgressIndicator()
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
}
```

You may try like this :

```
// Means that if the snapshot hasn't data show the widget
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried that, still get the same error.