# How to return object from lambda function in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, anonymous-function, dart-null-safety

Every way I try this it says either the result is null. So I have the function(which is medium) that explicitly returns a Map<String,int> and I'm using this lambda function to feed keys,values into it & this works with no "might return null" warnings

```
> players.forEach((k, v) => medium(k, v));
```

I've tried all the naïve ways like just assigning a variable to it, or wrapping it in a callable.

> Map<String, dynamic> souvenir(Map lamp) { return lamp.forEach((k, v) => medium(k, v)); }

Whatever way I put it the error is always something along the lines of:

```
"message": "A value of type 'void' can't be returned from the function 'souvenir' because it has a return type of 'Map<String, dynamic>'.",
```

Which makes sense because print statements in medium will work fine, but I don't know how to access the Map I'm returning.
If I could get a better way to iterate the keys/values or write it to Json that would work too. But I couldn't figure out how I could wrap it in a .toJson function without declaring an object when I was looking at'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/.

Answer (score 0):

**forEach** is a void method and it can't return anything. Try **map()** method. Maybe it helps in your case.

```
Map<String, dynamic> souvenir(Map lamp) { return lamp.map((k, v) => medium(k, v)); }
```